# Copying large number of files in windows

Tags: linux, windows

I am facing problem in copying a large number of file 18 lakh (18,000,000) files from my personal hardisk to another hardisk each file is very small and size of folder is around 3.95 GB copying files using copy given by Windows is frustrating and I am not even able to compress file its giving me error that its not readable.

And problem is I am not able to open this drive in Linux it showing me error there saying do diskchk in Windows and Windows disk check is also not able to repair this drive and goes into some mode unsolvable.

Is there any way to open disk with error to open in Windows and if not any way I can copy data faster?

```
ERROR: Disk labled EDU is corrupt go to windows and chkdsk /f there and reboot into window 2 times.
```

Please help me how to copy it faster to different harddisk.

Comment: 18 million or 18 lakhs??? 18,000,000 is 18 million ;)

Comment: I dont see a reason for Linux or Windoes to deny it. 4GB is not much. 18L is also not much. Do other copy procedures work properly?

Answer (score 1):

You may Try FastCopy, a third party software that copies files faster than windows does. But, I think you need to solve corruption issue in your hard drive first. Giving more details will be very useful:

Which windows version you have? (XP, Vista, 7)

What is the file system?(FAT32, NTFS)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the microsoft utility richcopy?
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [Teracopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php)  I've used it to copy large amounts of data with good results in the past.